# get uid or nid from an alias_url in Drupal 7

Tags: drupal

I would like to obtain uid in a page, i tried to use

```
global $node;
$nid = $node->nid;
global $user;
$userid = $user->uid
```

but it doesn't work my url is something like this

```
http://localhost/incollect/spencer-gallery
```

spencer-gallery is node alias
what can i do to get uid or nid in spencer-gallery page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the nid you can use the code below:

```
if (arg(0) == 'node' && is_numeric(arg(1))) {
  $nid = arg(1);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To follow on from Kevin's answer once you have the $nid you can user:

```
$node = node_load($nid);
```

And then the user id of the nodes author is accessible by:

```
$uid = $node->uid;
```